# how to have an model that is assigned to an object use an Active Model Serializer class for rendering

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3.2, active-model-serializers

I am not sure if this is possible but I am currently assigning some values to a Ruby object that I am then outputting via to_json

Like:

```
def current_results
  @post=Post.find(params[:id])
  r={}
  r[:name]=@post.name
  ....
  mi[:notes]=mi.notes
  r[:associated_items]  << mi
  ...
  render :json => r.to_json
```

end

Right now, notes outputs everything as I would somewhat expect. But I have a NoteSerializer which I thought would be invoked by the to_json (that's how I'm reading this section https://github.com/rails-api/active_model_serializers#render-json but not really sure). How could I get mi.notes to use the NoteSerializer rather than returning back the default of the whole object (updated_at, create_at ...)?

thx